# How do I move my IIS web site to be under the Default Web Site?

Tags: c#, iis, hosting

I have the Default Web Site in the IIS, i have a second web site that i want to use the same binding as the default. Right now it creates a second website.

[As is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POdEe.png)

I want move the website to be under the default web site like the one below.

[To be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmtI1.png)

I hope i made sense.

Comment: If you open `applicationHost.config`, then what you will do is 1) copy the default `<application>` tag from the second site to the first site. 2) change the application path there as the first site also as a default `<application>` tag. 3) delete the second site if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add application by right click default web site.

[image]

Then fill the alias and set physical path to your second application's folder.
[image]

At last, you can access the second site by http://localhost/alias.